# A better way for me to implement swapping elements in 2Darray with ArrowKeys input

Tags: c#, oop, multidimensional-array

I am new and looking to learn object oriented programing with c#. The problem I am facing is how would I make the current solution better or cleaner? I have a method inside my `board` class that functions as swapping tiles via the arrow keys.

```
        private void SwapTiles(int[,] arr, int n)
        {
            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;
            var isSorted = ArrSorted(arr);//method to check if array is sorted works!

            do
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine();

                if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
                {
                    if (y >= (n - 1))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                int temp = arr[x, y];
                arr[x, y] = arr[x, (y + 1)];
                arr[x, (y + 1)] = temp;
            } while (isSorted == true);

        }
```

As I was implementing my solution to the problem I realized that I would need to implement the same code multiple times but with slight variation for each arrow key. I dont know how I would achieve the same results cleaner. Any help on this matter would be appreciated and hints to links or other solutions is also appreciated as I am trying to learn.

Comment: Could you add a small example which may clarify what you want to do?